# Comparing two instances of a class in Java

Tags: java

I have a class with two integer members. These members are block and offset numbers. I need to compare two instances of this class with great or less signs. For example;

```
instance1 < instance2
```

statement needs to return true if

```
instance1.blockNumber < instance2.blockNumber;
```

or

```
instance1.blockNumber = instance2.blockNumber;
instance1.offset < instance2.offset;
```

As far as I know Java doesn't support operator overloading. How can I do this such comparison?

Comment: You can implement the `Comparable` interface. You still won't be able to write `instance1 < instance2`, though, but need to write `instance1.compareTo(instance2) < 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have the class implement the `Comparable` interface, which gives the `compareTo` method. You can then use the value of the number (`-1` for less, `1` for more, `0` for equals) in your if statements.

If you want to put these objects in lists (say, for sorting) you should also `@Override` the `.equals` method.

```
import java.util.Comparable;

public class BlockOffset implements Comparable<BlockOffset>
{
  private int blockNumber;
  private int offset;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(BlockOffset instance2) {
    if (this.blockNumber < instance2.blockNumber) return -1;
    if (this.blockNumber > instance2.blockNumber) return 1;
    if (this.offset < instance2.offset) return -1;
    if (this.offset > instance2.offset) return 1;

    return 0;
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the class type is your own code than you can have it implement `Comparable` and define the `compareTo` method where you can write the logic. Then, you can compare them using `compareTo`.

Comment: Am I able to use >, < signs?

Comment: No, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: @UmutDerbentoğlu: No, you can't overload `<` and `>` in Java, you will have to use `compareTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement and use `comparable` or `comparator`